# Error obteniendo valor de un campo de texto jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, formularios

Estoy intentando obtener el valor de un campo configurado con el [plugin intl-tel-input](https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input/blob/master/README.md), en el que pido al usuario que introduzca su número de teléfono. El problema es que, por algún motivo, a la hora de enviar los datos al servidor, el campo (con nombre `phone`) está vacío:

```
comments: "Comentario"
contact: "Correo"
email:"prueba@email.es"
name: "Xab"
phone: ""
read: true
surname: "Montoto"
zip: 1111
```

El `input` es este:

```
<div><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-200" name="phone" ng-model="vm.form.phonepasar" id="phone_pasar" ng-maxlength=15 maxlength=15 ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }"/>
```

Las opciones que he probado para sortear el error son:

1. Crear un campo oculto y copiar el valor del dato. Esto, efectivamente, permite pasar el valor al servidor. Sin embargo, al requerir el parámetro `required`, no puedo ponerlo ni en `type=hidden`, ni `display:none`, ni `visibility:hidden`, ya que aparentemente es necesario que el usuario modifique manualmente este campo para considerarse válido.
2. Utilizar el plugin [JSValidate](https://validatejs.org/) para ignorar el parámetro `required`. Tampoco ha funcionado.

¿Qué hay que hacer para que al llamar a la función `save()` pueda pasarle el valor del campo de teléfono al servidor?:

```
function save() {
    vm.isSaving = true;
    var valorOculto = $("#phone").intlTelInput("getNumber", intlTelInputUtils.numberFormat.E164);
    $("#phone").val(valorOculto);
    ContactaServiceRest.contacto(vm.form, onSaveSuccess, onSaveError);
}
```

Comment: El input está con el nombre "phone_pasar" cambiale el nombre por solo "phone" y probá

Answer (score 2):

Para poder extraer el numero formateado usando `intlTelInput("getNumber")` es necesario inicializar el plugin con la opcion `utilsScript`

```js
$("#phone").intlTelInput({
  utilsScript: "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/11.0.13/js/utils.js"
});

// update the hidden input on submit
$("form").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  $("#hidden").val($("#phone").intlTelInput("getNumber"));
  
  console.log($("#hidden").val())
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/11.0.13/css/intlTelInput.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/11.0.13/js/intlTelInput.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <input id="phone" type="tel" name="phone">
  <input id="hidden" type="hidden" name="phone-full">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

*fuente:* http://intl-tel-input.com/node_modules/intl-tel-input/examples/gen/hidden-input.html

Comment: Hola Luis,

He editado la pregunta. El campo tenía de nombre "phone_pasar" porque era el que estaba utilizando para pasar el dato al otro campo "phone". He editado la pregunta para evitar confusiones, pero lamentablemente esta no es la solución.

Answer (score 0):

Solo corrige el `name` del input,

```
<div><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-200" name="phone" ng-model="vm.form.phonepasar" id="phone" ng-maxlength=15 maxlength=15 ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }"/>
```

Claramente se ve en el `JS` que lo estas llamando `$("#phone")`

Comment: Hola Ivan,

He editado la pregunta. El campo tenía de nombre "phone_pasar" porque era el que estaba utilizando para pasar el dato al otro campo "phone". He editado la pregunta para evitar confusiones, pero lamentablemente esta no es la solución.

Comment: En tu funcion Save estas capturando un `id` en `JQuery` para tener el valor de un `id` se usa el `#` por eso tu funcion busca el `id` llamado `phone` y no lo encuentra ya que `phone`  esta como name y para esto tiens que poner  `$('input[name=phone]')`